# How I can get result of each test in Detox?

Tags: javascript, detox

I want to create integration with my TMS in order to save autotests results with tests, stored in the TMS:

1. Create test run (done by me)
2. Add all run test cases to it (done by me)
3. **Pass results of this cases to the created test run (here is the issue)**
4. Complete run on end autotests (also done by me)

I use Detox for running tests, but didn't get how to get test result of each test.
I've found Detox ArtifactPlugin.test.js, where is operations around test results shown:

```
class TestArtifactPlugin extends ArtifactPlugin {}

describe('ArtifactPlugin', () => {
  let api;
  let plugin;

  beforeEach(() => {
    api = {
      userConfig: {
        enabled: false,
        keepOnlyFailedTestsArtifacts: false,
      },
    };

    plugin = new TestArtifactPlugin({ api });
  });

    it('should have .onTestDone, which updates context.testSummary if called', async () => {
          const testSummary = testSummaries.failed();
          await plugin.onTestDone(testSummary);
          expect(plugin.context.testSummary).toBe(testSummary);
        });
}
```

I want it to be done somehow like this:

```
let testResults = []
let testResult = {}

afterEach(async () => {
  await testResults.push({
    testID: context.testSummary.ID,
    result: context.testSummary.result
  })
})
```